# Need laptop for programming: durable, reliable, fast and long battery life

Tags: laptop, linux, windows

Regarding of the extreme slowness of the computer with whom I work, and saw that I'd like to use the laptop for personal purposes, I was thinking of buying a laptop suited to programming. 
I can keep a big-budget (1500 €) but I want a PC that allows me to not have any kind of slowdown and speed of compilation / execution of programs for the next 5 years.
Consequently, the PC must be suitable for programming and last long. 
Traveling a lot, if it were light it would be great.

You who would you recommend with these requirements?

Europe market (Italy) / last quarter 2016

Answer (score 3):

The Razer Blade Stealth looks insanely good and is the laptop I would definitely buy if I had the money... It will suit all your needs at the price you want, but it might be slightly overkill, however, if you want the fastest possible I suggest this one

[Razer Site](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-systems/razer-blade-stealth)

[Amazon Page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L3EX8Y6)

I think macs also do a fine job and I see lots of programmers using them, but I don't really like Mac OS and don't know enough about them to give good advice

Comment: I can give a +1 for the Mac. For the record, I had Windows laptops and still a Windows desktop. But the Mac *was* beneficial to me for development because of the UNIX environment and availability of commercial software tools. I presume that has changed a bit now that Windows recently released the Ubuntu Bash. But I'm not 100% sure that the Windows Bash is a 100% bash shell. It may have some things missing/unsupported since it's still technically in beta. **TL;DR** Get the OS you like the most, but remember you may spend lots of time in Linux/UNIX environments.

Comment: +1. Blade Stealth and MB/P are your best bet for mobile workstations that don't require high end GPUs or niche specs at this price point.